# Keep a point on a rotating line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm developing a software program where I can draw lines and have a question regarding geometry. I have a line which can rotate 360 degrees. There is an arrow connected to the end of the line. This arrow is rotating depending on the angle of the line. My problem is that the endpoint and the arrow is not completely in sync. There is an offset that needs to be calculated. However, I can't just add a constant of e.g. 5 to x and y since the offset changes when it rotates. The picture shows this. At 0 degrees the offset i -5X and -5Y. At 90 5X and -5Y. At 180 5X and 5Y. At -90 -5X and 5Y. Between these point the offset will be something else I guess. Is there a way top calculate the offset depending on the angle?

[image]

Comment: Are you really at the good place to ask for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the offset at `0°` be `(X, Y)`. (This answer is general and supports 2D offsets).

Then for any angle

```
X' = X cos(Θ) - Y sin(Θ)
Y' = X sin(Θ) + Y cos(Θ)
```

Comment: @DavidK: yep, didn't proofread, shame on me.

Comment: The programmer should note that the `sin` and `cos` functions in most software libraries expect the input in radians, not degrees, so if you measure your angles in degrees usually you have to multiply the angle Θ by a constant, $\pi/180$ (in software `3.14159265358979/180`), before applying `sin` or `cos`. That's what we call a "minor detail of implementation."

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted, thanks! Do you also know how to offset the arrow towards the center? The arrow should e.g. be 20 points from the edge of the line.

Comment: @Abris: this is already answered.